# Bring element to the front using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've made the following buttons with CSS:
[Screenshot of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSo6z.png)

With the follwing CSS code:

```
.boton-cabezera {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 8px 15px;
}

.boton-cabezera a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFA12B;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=0px, offy=1px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFE5C4, 0 10px 0 #915100;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFE5C4, 0 10px 0 #915100;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFE5C4, 0 10px 0 #915100;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.boton-cabezera a:active {
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #F78900;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFE5C4, inset 0 -3px 0 #915100;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFE5C4, inset 0 -3pxpx 0 #915100;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFE5C4, inset 0 -3px 0 #915100;
}

.boton-cabezera:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: -4px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #2B1800;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

To create a button you just need to create a 'div' with the class "boton-cabezera" and add a 'a' tag.

When pressed the buttons look like this:
[Screenshot of button pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMV2c.png)

I've made this buttons for a minesweeper game.

My problem is that one of the buttons used in the game doesn't look like my other buttons. I think it is a z-index problem, but I can't seem to figure it out on my own.

I've made a modal that asks for the players name when he ends the game.
[Screenshot of the modal and the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Hek.png)
As you can appreciate in the SS the button doesnt look like the ones in the header. It doesn't have that button container look. The ":after" that ive included in the CSS seems to not be working here.

Here is the modal CSS code:

```
.mensaje-bg {
    /*El display se cambia a block con jquery*/
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mensaje {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 12% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 260px;
    border: solid #0f0f0f 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-bottom: solid 5px black;
}
```

And here is the HTML code for the modal part:

```
<div id="mensaje-bg" class="mensaje-bg">
        <div class="mensaje">
            <estado-carita id="emoji">
                <i class="fas fa-frown"></i>
            </estado-carita>
            <estado-final id="estado-final">
                ¡Perdiste!
            </estado-final>
            <tiempo-total id="tiempo-total">
                Tu tiempo fue de 00:00 en dificultad media.
            </tiempo-total>
            <label id="label-nombre" for="nombre">¿Cual es tu nombre?</label>
            <input id="j" type="text" placeholder="Tu nombre">
            <div class="boton-cabezera">
                <a href="#" id="siguiente" class="nuevo_juego">
                    Siguiente &nbsp;
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right">
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you dev tools say about the `after` pseudo? Does it appear at all?

Comment: yes it appears, but i think it is behind the modal.and only the button itslef shows on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to specify `z-index:1` for `boton-cabezera a` style and also set `z-index:0` for `.boton-cabezera:after` style

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-kare-mpont?file=/index.html)

```css
.boton-cabezera a {
    /*...Other Styles...*/
    
   z-index: 1;
  
}

.boton-cabezera:after {
    /*...Other Styles...*/
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.